# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot(+JPA/Hibernate) application using MySQL. Running it, I get this:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
    
Description:
    
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
    
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

This is my application.properties file (the last one is used for injecting in the other module):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
rest.url=http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users
```

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RunApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RunApp.class, args);
    }
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Make sure your properties file is in the right location (in the resources folder). An if you use IntelliJ make sure your resources folder is marked as 'resources root' folder.

Comment: One more thing: by default spring boot looks for application.properties. So if you renamed your file to let's say application-dev.properties you should run your application with the param -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: I've checked the whole classpath, including the resources directory and the application.properties. I think the reason should be dependencies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that the packaging attribute was **pom**. So I changed that into **war**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the driver class: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work :)